# how to make text go to the next line instead of being cut

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
<div className={css.serviceInfo}>
        {availableServicesArray.map(service => {
          return(
            <span className={css.extraInfoLabel}>{service}</span>
          )
        })}
      </div>
```

which renders like this :

[image]

My question is: How can I make the `span`'s text not be cut and go to the next line instead. I have tried with `white-space:nowrap` and `white-space: initial`but none work.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Give display inline-block to the span

Comment: Thanks man! it worked. Feeling silly now for how easy it was

Comment: No worries. Please support me by accepting the answer and upvoting. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the `span`